# Include legend functionality (toggling) in D3 graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, legend

I've made a graph using http://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/ for data visualization.

Code used :

```
//data :
// [{date:new Date('2013-01-01'),n:120,n3:124,ci_up:130,ci_down:118} ...]
var chart = d3.timeseries()
  .addSerie(data,{x:'timestamp',y:'a'},{interpolate:'linear',color:"#a6cee3",label:"value"})
  .addSerie(data,
      {x:'timestamp',y:'b'},
      {interpolate:'monotone',dashed:true,color:"#a6cee3",label:"prediction"})
  .width(900)

chart('#chart')
```

I'm including multiple lines in graph by adding addSeri method.

I want to include the functionality where in I can make these lines visible or invisible depending on what user wan to see in graph.

It should be something like [this](http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav). How do i include this functionality in my graph?

I already have multiple lines in graph, I just need toggling feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is there any functionality to update your chart data? 
if the answer is yes, then you only need to add a new flag to your main data and enable/disable it when user clicks on legends and redraw or update your chart. at the draw function, you must check if the flag is enabled for each line and then allow it to be drawn.

but if you don't have update functionality... then.. maybe its a solution to get a reference of your lines after ( or at the time of ) appending to your parent container, then by clicking on legends make all dots to zero but still you have to re-draw your axis if you want to achieve the given example.. so I can suggest you make a update functionality to your chart that you can re-draw your chart based on new data.

Update : I just thought you are developing a D3 chart from scratch but after I posted this i noticed you are using an script which has functions to generate a line chart based on D3.js

Update 2: 
As I'm not sure how exactly your entire script might look I can only guess this might work for you... 
place a button some where at your HTML ( outside of your chart element)

```
<button onclick="toggleLine('.ci-area',1)">Toggle Spreaded Region</button>
<button onclick="toggleLine('.line',1)">Toggle Line 1</button>
<button onclick="toggleLine('.line',2)">Toggle Line 2</button>
```

and also add this at bottom of your chart script

```
function toggleLine(selector,index){
   var line = d3.selectAll(selector).filter(function(d,i){ return i==index-1;});

  // so here we get a reference to initial opacity if its not always "1"
  if(!line.attr("initial-opacity")){
        line.attr("initial-opacity",line.style('opacity'));
  }


  line.style('opacity',(line.style('opacity')==0 ? line.attr("initial-opacity") : 0));
}
```

btw you can also use a CSS class and toggle it for your selected graph element, like :

```
.hide-graph-element{ opacity:0 }
```

Hope it helps.